# Benefit of putting Image stream directly in css

Tags: css, optimization

Would it be faster to put the image directly into css because it reduces the amount of DNS/http requests?

**Image directly in css:**

```
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAK7CAYAAAAz2+WzAAAAZElEQVRIx+2WwQ4AEAxDGz7X/5/rG8TaCi49iD3bxBQARgOAL1+kwuLNlKXBYigNfaEWQAWZ2nq5seYNs6F0EUuUQOISQGGbbICbT/NeaOCp8eIZ8cbMPvM3jXqLlJfKGs2+wpvWvG54wI6NvgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
```

**Image indirectly in css:**

```
background: url('images/wrapper-bg.png');
```

Comment: well... err, this feels somehow wrong. This reminds me of the time, when everyone thought it would be a super good idea to store images into a database and let php receive them on pageload. dns is usally cached and fast. And the traffic stays the same... so please dont put it into css files, I think browsers will wait till css file is loaded completely, wheras they dont do that for images by default

Comment: how are you going to put the base64 converted image stream inside the CSS file? By hard-coding it?

Comment: Yup, hard-coding would do

Comment: Hardcoding? Horrible idea!

Comment: Why? Do you suggest using JS?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work anyway since JS usually runs on the client side... But imagine the mess when you put your images in your CSS file - nobody can simply look at the image without actually loading the CSS in a browser etc, you can't simply edit it, ....

Comment: Are you sure ? What if you want to change it in future? So what I am guessing is in that case you need to run a script to get the base64 encode text for that image and put it there again.. sounds crazy to me

Comment: You should typically handle this sort of thing at the server end.

Comment: your base64'd image would be approx. 37% larger than the original one. You'll have fewer requests, but more payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of an optimisation-too-far.

It's really tempting to think about it purely in terms of reducing the number of http requests; cut down the requests, and you'll cut down the load time, right?

Well, yes, that's right. But you need to consider other performance aspects as well. If you only consider one aspect of performance, it is easy to compromise your performance in other areas.

- File size: Base64 encoding adds an extra 37% to the size of your image. So for every 10k file, that's an extra 3.5k you're adding on top if you base64 encode it.
- Decoding: Base64 has to be decoded by the browser back into a regular image file before it can be processed normally. This takes time. Possibly as much time as you're saving with reducing the http request.
- Caching: Browsers cache things. This is good and helps us reduce downloads, and it applies to both CSS and images. But of course, if you make changes to your site, the changed file needs to be re-downloaded. If that changed file contains all your images as well, then it means re-downloading the whole lot, rather than just a small bit. The more stuff you cram into a single file, the more likely it will be for a small change to your site to force that single file to need to be re-loaded by all the browsers that have previously cached it.
- Maintenance: Optimisnig your site performance on the browser is great, but unless you're really squeezing every drop of speed out of your site, you should put the maintainability of your code at a similar level of priority (if not higher). Data-URIs are not easy to work with. There are tools that can help, but ultimately, if you've got a simple image file, and a plain-text CSS file, it is easier to read, easier to work with, easier to replace elements when you need to, and easier to debug. Think about your own performance, as well as that of your code.

You might want to read [this recent article on the subject](http://www.mobify.com/blog/css-sprites-vs-data-uris-which-is-faster-on-mobile/) (and the other articles linked from it).

The short answer is that if you're using a data-URI specifically to reduce http requests from images for performance reasons, then you're unlikely to get the performance gains you're hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it's not a good idea to put your images right in the css.** Browsers cache things anyway so except during the first load it won't make anything faster. Not to forget the horrible mess you get by putting image data in your CSS...

Additionally, when you send proper caching headers and maybe even use timestamped URLs (i.e. the mtime of the resource is part of its URL) you can tell browsers to cache everything for a long time and when you change something it will be reloaded from the server.

Comment: +1 for the header caching, actually if such images are not going to change much often in future then setting such a header would definitely help

Comment: Even if they do change - timestamped URLs allow you to cache them anyway